# Importing external data with different field format

Tags: migration

I have the source file in Excel as follows:

> Item-------Reference---Description
>   -400020--20045-------Ruler 60cms
>   8900032--20012-------Eraser 45gr

Notes:
Because I can add many spaces here, the dash"-" denotes a space on the original file
The Item 400020 comes with a space before the 4 from the source.

The following file is the expected with the proper format to be exported to our DB

> Item--------Reference---Description
>   0400020--0020045-----Ruler
>   60cms    8900032--0020012-----Eraser 45gr

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to convert numbers in excel table to characters first, and adjust the data (spaces). Export to CSV, and then import into database. I suppose you have varchar datatype for `Item` and `Reference` columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

A history of using Excel has convinced me that Excel formatting should not be relied upon. And it is, in fact, difficult to influence on the fly.

Assuming Microsoft SQL Server, you could use a linked server query to read from the Excel spreadsheet or you could load the data into a staging table.  Such as:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StagingExcel
(Item CHAR(7),
 Reference CHAR(7),
 Description VARCHAR(50));
```

Load the data into the `StagingExcel` table, then transfer the data, properly formatted, to the target table.  E.g.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTargetTable (Item, Reference, Description)
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + Item,7),
       RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + Reference,7), 
       Description
FROM dbo.StagingExcel -- (or the Excel linked server)
```

**EDIT:** My comment on Excel formatting is simply that you also have to control the Excel columns.  If the Excel spreadsheet is all defined as text column, the results are predictable.

In the three columns below I typed the same strings in `AutoFormat` and `Text` columns, but see how differently they are displayed. Then I copied the `AutoFormat` values into `AutoFormatToText` column and got the `AutoFormat` values, but justified as `Text`.

```
**AutoFormat    Text       AutoFormatToText**
  12/21/1934    12/21/34   12/21/1934
       12345    12345      12345
         123    000123     123
```

Your comment seems to imply that the first two columns combine into a single key value. Assuming the format to be two 0-justified 7-character columns becoming a 14-character column you would just concatenate the two columns.  Snippet:

```
       ...
       RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + Item,7) + 
       RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + Reference,7), 
       ...
```

Comment: Points to take in considerations are: All fields must be text format, we have kind of item number, the ones that start on 04XXXX and the starting on 89XXXX (Both numbers are combined on the same extracted file).